# Tkinter window not showing up (even after using mainloop)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a customized type of tk root for my app (So that I don't have to reconfigure all the layout for a TopLevel), but the **mainloop method is not working** (My app window is not displaying).

Here is how I proceeded:

```
from tkinter import *

class a_customized_window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title("A custom window")

win=a_customized_window()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: You did not call the `__init__()` of the inherited class: add `super().__init__()` inside `__init__()` of the custom class.

Comment: That's an infinite loop.  `self.mainloop()` will call itself until the stack overflows.  You need  to use `super().mainloop()`, in addition to forwarding the `__init__` call as @acw1668 said.

Comment: @TimRoberts can you provide a code sample, this will help in clarifying things for me, because I still don't know how to proceed exactly

Comment: I'm... still waiting

Comment: _I'm... still waiting_ -- that's very rude.  We are all volunteers here, and my post was just before midnight in my time zone.  I gave you enough clues that you could have looked this up on your own.

Comment: @TimRoberts I said nothing about you, all I was complaining about is that I asked for a simple code sample when you were supposedly still active (Just one minute after your answer), and then I literally spent 90 minutes editing and re-editing my post just so that it stays at the top of the recommendations because no one answered it properly. You can imagine the frustration I went through just for a simple code to continue my beginner app.
Edit: Thanks for your help tho, I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `__init__()` of the parent class inside `__init__()` of the custom class:

```py
from tkinter import *

class a_customized_window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("A custom window")

win=a_customized_window()
win.mainloop()
```